# 90s film about one alien controlling humans and making them act violently

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I am trying to remember the name of a movie I saw when I was a kid (90s). This is about an alien (I vaguely remember being a black scorpion type) that was moving from human to human (as they got killed) and controlling their mind, making them act violently.

The only scene I can clearly remember is that the action takes place in the street at night, after one human was killed, the hero (a man) sees the alien quickly run on the ground and move onto another human.

Comment: Any small detail you can add would help, like do you remember any other details of other scenes even if not so clearly? Do you remember the over all plot?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I cannot remember much of it. I am guessing that at the end the hero kills the alien, but that is just pure guess as I do not remember the plot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good contender would be ["*The Hidden*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hidden_(film)), a 1987 SF/Horror movie with body jumping aliens and lots of violence:

> Meanwhile, at the hospital, DeVries suddenly awakens. Disconnecting
> his life-support equipment, he approaches the comatose man in the next
> bed, Jonathan P. Miller (William Boyett). After DeVries forces
> Miller's mouth open, a slug-like alien emerges from DeVries' mouth and
> transfers itself into Miller's body. Gallagher arrives to find DeVries
> dead on the floor and Miller's bed abandoned. Gallagher tells Beck to
> put out an alert on Miller, who refuses, because of Miller's lack of a
> criminal history.
>
> Miller goes to a record store where he beats the store's owner to
> death. He then goes to a car dealership, where he kills three men and
> steals a red Ferrari. He then visits a strip club, where the alien
> leaves Miller's body and takes over the body of a stripper named
> Brenda (Claudia Christian)
>
> <sub>(Wikipedia)</sub>

You can see the trailer below:

Comment: This is what I thought of, as well.  +1

Answer (score 3):

One possibility would be [*The Puppet Masters*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111003/) from 1994.

Here is a clip with one of the aliens. (Never mind the monkeys.)

I can't seem to get a sharp enough frame for a screenshot, sorry.

Comment: I did think of this one from the description and was in the middle of writing an answer when the OP accepted the other one. Unfortunately, like I said another is accepted but this is certainly helpful to others remembering a similar story.

Comment: I only saw that the other answer was accepted after I hit post here. Shall I delete this one, or shall I keep it up in case anyone is looking for _The Puppet Masters_ and stumbles upon this question?

Comment: Per above, keep it up :)